# Request token for signing group recipient using SOAP API

Tags: c#, docusignapi

Are signing group supported by SOAP API, or is it only by REST?
I was able to create and send envelope with signing group recipient. Instead of Name and Email I added signing group and set `SigningGroupIdSpecified` to true:

```
envelope.Recipients[1] =
  recipients.Where(r = > r.RoutingOrder == SigningOrder.Second)
    .Select(recipientParam =
              > new Recipient{ID = recipientParam.ID,
                              //UserName = recipientParam.Name,
                              //Email = recipientParam.Email,
                              Type           = RecipientTypeCode.Signer,
                              RoutingOrder   = (ushort)recipientParam.RoutingOrder,
                              SigningGroupId = recipientParam.SigningGroupId,
                              SigningGroupIdSpecified = true

                })
    .FirstOrDefault();
```

Now, it seems the only way in SOAP API to get token is using method:

```
RequestRecipientToken(envelopeId, ClientUserID, recipient.Name, recipient.Email, assert, urls);
```

There is no place to put signing group Id and doesn't matter if I send recipient name and email or not I always receive error message:

> Additional information: The recipient you have identified is not a valid recipient of the specified envelope.